# Copy xml node value to another node value in the same xml file

Tags: xml, copy

My code looks like this:

```
<element1 id="value1" classname="">
    <element2>value2</element2>
</element1>
```

And there's alot of these in the xml file.

I want to copy each `<element1 id="value1">` for every xml fragment (value 1 is always different of course) and insert value 1 to value 2 in `<element2>value2</element2>` in the same xml fragment.

For example:

I want to transform every xml fragment from something like this...

```
<element1 id="1252" classname="">
    <element2>"25"</element2>
</element1>
```

to this...

```
<element1 id="1252" classname="">
    <element2>"1252"</element2>
</element1>
```

I'd be very happy if anyone could help me! :D

Comment: You should make a program to do that... It would be easier to provide more guidance if you told about what kind of programming tools you can make use of.

Comment: I might be easiest with a php script, but if anyone has another solution I would probably be able to use any programming tool.